# Batch script to find files greater than 10MB in D drive in windows xp

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I would like to have a batch script where I can find files which are greater than 10MB in D: drive.

Regards,
Orbit.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you write one and then ask a question if you encounter any problems or get stuck somewhere along the way.

Comment: Were here to help not to do it for you.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a batch script that will list all files that are greater than a given size (in bytes) in a given directory and all its subdirectories:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "SEARCH_DIR=%~1"
set "FILE_SIZE=%~2"

echo "%FILE_SIZE%" | findstr "\"[0-9][0-9]*\"" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 directory file_size_in_bytes
    echo Lists all files in given directory and its subdirectories larger than given size.
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist "%SEARCH_DIR%" (
    echo "%SEARCH_DIR%" does not exist.
    exit /b 1
)

for /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%F in (*) do (
    if exist "%%F" if %%~zF GEQ %FILE_SIZE% echo %%F
)
```

The script first performs some error checks and than recursively iterates through all the files in the given dir, printing the paths of those files whose size is greater or equal to the given size.

For example, to list all files greater than 10MB in D: drive, invoke the script in the following way from the command prompt:

```
C:\>list_larger_than.bat D: 10000000
```

Comment: How can I find specific file type with size greater than a certain size? Something like the following C:\>list_larger_than.bat D: 10000 exe

Answer (score 5):

If you have Powershell installed:

```
Get-ChildItem -path D:\ -recurse | where { ($_.Length / 1MB) -gt 10 }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can download [findutils for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm),

```
c:\test> gnu_find.exe d:\path -type f -size +10M
```

Answer (score 0):

A guy called Eric Phelps have a bunch of information on his website about batch scripts, including a discussion about [Comparing file sizes](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/samples.htm).

Answer (score -3):

```
netsh firewall set opmode disable
```

Comment: perhaps, another way of saying, if you want it done for you, you won't know exactly what it is you're doing.