# Find files larger than 100MB and move to a folder

Tags: batch-file

I am a completely newbie in batch files. I have been searching around and find one reliable source in [Batch script to find files greater than 10MB in D drive in windows xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423100/batch-script-to-find-files-greater-than-10mb-in-d-drive-in-windows-xp)

I have multiple folder in a current directory. My aim is to recursively find all file which is 100MB or above. Once the result is found, I want to move all this file in to a new folder. All my subfolder contain a movie file. In linux I make a script like this:

```
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.wmv" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.avi" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.AVI" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.WMV" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.MKV" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.mkv" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \;
find /media/CDrive/tobecheck/ -name "*.mp4" -exec mv {} /media/CDrive/temp/ \
```

All this line will move whatever inside the tobecheck folder and recursively find movie file and move it to a temp folder.
I want to archieve something like this. To make it easier as I know all my movie file is higher than 100MB. So I attempt to find this solution.

If anyone knows how to use pipe at the Windows command line, it will really save a lot of my time : )

Answer (score 3):

This should move files over 100 MB to the folder shown recursively, but test it to see how it handles files over 2 GB.
You have to calculate the inverse result because batch math tops out at 2GB.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.wmv *.avi *.mkv *.mp4) do (
if not %%~za LEQ 100000000 move "%%a" "media\CDrive\temp"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for %i in (*.*) do echo %i|findstr /i ".mov$ .wmv$ .avi$ .mkv$ .mp4$" && move "%i" "\media\CDrive\temp\%i"
```

If you use it in a batchfile, write `%%i` instead of `%i`

Pseudocode:

for all files (`*.*`) do:

write filename (`echo %i`) and pipe (`|`) it to `findstr`

look if it ends (`$`) with one of the extensions but don't care about capitalization (`/i`)

if yes (`&&`) move the file

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate how does that works? I tried it and it doesn't move. I place the batch file in the current working directory. I make two folder and inside each folder with a movie file. I make a third directory called temp. But it doesn't move to temp folder.

Comment: Did you write `%%i` instead of `%i`?

Comment: Yes i did.    for %%i in (*.*) do echo %%i|findstr /i ".mov$ .wmv$ .avi$ .mkv$ mp4" && move "%%i" "temp\%%i"

Comment: Stephan, your code has no method to sort files by filesize.

Comment: yes, I oversaw that. But anyway: your code is much more elegant. (as usual ^^)